# HP StorageWorks MSA60 SAS attached enclosure: how to manage online on Windows?

Tags: windows, hp, hardware-raid, sas, hp-smart-array

We have a HP StorageWorks MSA60 SAS attached enclosure, with 12x1Tb SATA disks, connected to a P800 controller.
Until now, they were used with a Linux server under the control of an external company.
We no longer need this Linux server.

We now want to use them into a Windows server, as storage disk (we already have a system disk).
I installed the P800 card, connected the MSA60, configured with the offline utility, installed the drivers. Work fine.

I then installed HP Array Configuration Utility. This allow me to VIEW controller and disks state. I don't find any way to MANAGE (ie change RAID level, etc, as with the offline utility).

I also installed HP Systems Insight Manager (mega-overkill...) but no more manage ability found.

My question is: how can I manage this P800 + MSA60 while Windows is running ?

Comment: What does the manual for the MSA60 say about managing it?

Comment: The manual says I should be able do manage it online with the tools I already installed: "The MSA60 features familiar configuration and management tools such as Array Configuration Utility (ACU) and HP Systems Insight Manager (SIM). Online Management Features include: Online Capacity Expansion, Online RAID Level Migration, Online Stripe Size Migration, Online Spares"

Comment: So when you open ACU via the Insight manager page, you're saying there is no configuration options there?

Comment: Nothing related to disks. I only have configuration options for cache settings, reconstruction priority, etc. But for logical and physical disks, I only have "suppress" and "more informations".

Comment: From the documentation it appears that is it... are you logged into SIM as Administrator? Maybe its hiding some options due to privileges.

Comment: Are you using an HP server?

Comment: And what type of changes are you trying to make to the array setup?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have the same hardware. There is just NO possibility to manage disks online. On only have access to status. This is one of the worst situation I ever seen.

Comment: That is incorrect. This setup is manageable online either from the graphical utility or the `hpacucli` CLI utility.

Comment: Agree with ewwhite - you're dead-wrong about this Gregory, we have LOTS of Px00 series cards connected to lots of MSA x0 boxes and in every case you absolutely can manage the whole thing with ACU or hpacucli utility.

Comment: I'm maybe dead wrong, but seems I'm not the only one unable to manage anything of value with ACU. So if this is so simple, just explain how to do it. I send hours installing/uninstalling, trying, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Login to the ACU using your system's Administrator username and password. This could simply be a permissions issue. Also, do you have the command line utility installed (hpacucli)? Try that while logged in as Administrator. The command line syntax is a little tricky, but you should be able to make the necessary changes.

See the [MSA 60 overview page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00911095&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=3302295&prodTypeId=12169).

```
Array Configuration Utility (ACU)   
Provides a graphical view of HP drive array configurations
Easy to use Wizards for configuration
Web Based ACU supports On-Line, Remote Web Based and Off-line configuration
Supports on-line configuration for *Microsoft*, NetWare and Linux
```

Another question. When you mentioned offline utility, were you just working with the BIOS, or did you use the [HP SmartStart CD](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-fa4e107ffbbd4ef394e57dd739%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to boot into the Array Configuration Utility? You should really do the initial work there if possible.

Also be sure to update the firmware on the server, controller, enclosure and disks. Especially since this is a repurposed server. You can use the bootable [HP Firmware DVD](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-94560dcc34e845edbb13a26792%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to accomplish this all at once.

Comment: I'm already logged on as administrator. I have CLI utility, but this is too easy to shoot my own foot with it. I use the HP SmartStart CD for offline management.

Comment: The configuration utility on the SmartStart CD is the same ACU that you're running under Windows.  The only difference is that the CD version doesn't have any notion of account privileges or permissions.  There's probably something subtle in your system's configuration that is causing a permissions issue.  I'm looking at a test system with pretty much the same hardware setup as yours and I'm seeing the full set of ACU options.